# Match two .txt files and export to excel with python

Tags: python, excel, for-loop, iteration, match

I am new to python and I am trying to match the data I have extracted from two .txt in a way that if the first element of each line of each file coincides with the first element of each line of each file it should give an output that will write that information on a excel sheet.
So far this is what I have got but I am getting blocked so I would appreciate any help.
I just iterate using for-loops so I do not know how to do it so that I can compare between the two files and if there is match to write it without the for loops

```
import xlwt
c1=-1
c2=0

file1=open('/Users/whatever.txt','r')
file2=open('/Users/whatever2.txt','r')

style0=xlwt.easyxf('font:name Times New Roman,colour black,bold on')
wb=xlwt.Workbook()

ws=wb.add_sheet('x',cell_overwrite_ok=True)

ws2=wb.add_sheet('y',cell_overwrite_ok=True)
row=0
row2=0

for lineA in file1:

    split=lineA.split('\t')
    split.pop(5)
    split.pop(5)
    split.pop(6)
    split.pop(6)
    split.pop(6)
    split.pop(6)
    split.pop(7)
    split.pop(7)
    split.pop(7)
    if '123\n'in split:
        continue
    elif '567\n' in split:
        continue
    elif '8910\n' in split:
        continue
    else:
        ws.write(0,0,euk,style0)
        ws.write(row,0,str(c1),style0)
        ws.write(row,1,split[0],style0)
        ws.write(row,2,split[1],style0)
        ws.write(row,3,split[2],style0)
        ws.write(row,4,split[3],style0)
        ws.write(row,5,split[4],style0)
        ws.write(row,6,split[5],style0)
        ws.write(row,7,split[6],style0)
        ws.write(row,8,split[7],style0)

        row+=1

for lineB in file2:

    split1=lineB.split('\t')
    split1.pop(5)
    split1.pop(5)
    split1.pop(5)
    split1.pop(5)
    split1.pop(5)
    split1.pop(5)
    split1.pop(5)
    split1.pop(-2)
    split1.pop(-2)
    split1.pop(-2)


  if '654\n' in split1:

        ws2.write(0,0,prok,style0)
        ws2.write(row2,0,str(c2),style0)
        ws2.write(row2,1,split1[0],style0)
        ws2.write(row2,2,split1[1],style0)
        ws2.write(row2,3,split1[2],style0)
        ws2.write(row2,4,split1[3],style0)
        ws2.write(row2,5,split1[4],style0)
        ws2.write(row2,6,split1[5],style0)
        ws2.write(row2,7,split1[6],style0)
        #print(split1)
        c2=c2+1
        row2+=1

wb.save('Hello.xls')
```

Comment: It seems like you're just trying to compare two files, and if the first few characters match, you want to put the matching text into a cell, but if it doesn't match, you want it to be put in the excel anyways?

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how to compare each first element of each list that is each line of the document with all the first elements of each list of eachline of the other file

Answer (score 0):

I think I follow what you are trying to do. Comparing the first element of each line shouldn't be too difficult. Try the following:

```
file1=open('/Users/whatever.txt','r')
file2=open('/Users/whatever2.txt','r')

for line in file1.readlines():
    # Split the line by tab spaces
    split_line = line.split('/t')
    # get the first element
    l1 = split_line[0]
    # Split the first line of file2 by tab spaces
    split_line2 = file2.readline().split("/t")
    # Get the first element of the file2 split line
    l2 = split_line2[0]

    # Check if they match
    if l1 == l2:
        # If they match, add it to your file
        # Add your write code here
    # If they don't match, nothing will be written
```

The following should do the same, but is more concise:

```
for line in file1.readlines():
    if line.split("/t")[0] == file2.readline().split("/t")[0]:
        # Add your write code here
```